# For $a,b,c>0$ proving $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \geqslant a + b + c + \frac{4(a - b)^2}{a + b + c}$

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

The problem with which I have a problem it's this:

> For $a,b,c>0$ prove that
> $$
> \frac{a^2}{b} + 
> \frac{b^2}{c} + 
> \frac{c^2}{a} \geqslant
> a + b + c +
> \frac{4(a - b)^2}{a + b + c}
> $$

Titu's Lemma and AM-GM work no good because this similar looking inequality is sharper.
After trying these, I decided to go for the following.

*Here is my work:*
Multiply $abc(a + b + c)$ to both the sides,
$$
(a + b + c)
(a^3c + ab^3 + bc^3) \geqslant abc(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ca) + 4abc (a - b) ^2
$$
After some work we are left to prove that:
$$
\sum_{cyc} {a^2b^3 + ab^4 - 2a^2 b^2 c} \geqslant abc(4 a^2 + 4 b^2 - 8ab)
$$
How to prove this or there is some better approach?
This inequality was the first in a list of many inequalities, but I don't think that means it is easy.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b}-\sum_{cyc }a=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b}-2a+b\right)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2}{b}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a-b+c-b+a-c)^2}{a+b+c}=\frac{4(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}.$$

Comment: I don't know how I missed this... Wow!

Answer (score 3):

The SOS proof. We have
$$\frac{a^2}{b} + 
\frac{b^2}{c} + 
\frac{c^2}{a} - 
(a + b + c) -
\frac{4(a - b)^2}{a + b + c}$$
$$=\frac{a(b^2-2bc+ca)^2+b(c^2-ab)^2+c(a^2-2ab+bc)^2}{abc(a+b+c)} \geqslant 0.$$

Comment: But where are $(a - b)^2$ and other like terms? I think that is in the definition ... so they should be there.

Comment: Why need $(a-b)^2$ terms?

Comment: $S_c(a-b)^2+S_b(a-c)^2+S_a(b-c)^2 \ge 0$. Writing an inequality in this form is the first step to applying S.O.S. as far as I know. But your last inequality shows all terms are positive so it's proof. Is it some other S.O.S.?

Comment: Can you add please your answer that how did you factorize these?